# Kendo Grid column does not sort properly when using rowtemplate

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with row templates .I am reordering the column and then sorting the same column.But kendo grid is interchanging the column data automatically.In example provided below ,I have two columns pictures and details column.I am reordering reordering these two columns and then applying sorting on details column.When I do this application just interchanging the c

Below is the example code snippets

```
    <div id="example">
        <table id="grid">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="photo" />
                <col class="details"/>
                <col/>
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Picture
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Details
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Country
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        ID
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
            <tr data-uid="#: uid #">
                <td class="photo">
                   <img src="../content/web/Employees/#:data.EmployeeID#.jpg" alt="#: data.EmployeeID #" />
                </td>
                <td class="details">
                   <span class="name">#: FirstName# #: LastName# </span>
                   <span class="title">Title: #: Title #</span>
                </td>
                <td class="country">
                    #: Country #
                </td>
                <td class="employeeID">
                   #: EmployeeID #
                </td>
           </tr>
        </script>
        <script id="altRowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
            <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="#: uid #">
                <td class="photo">
                   <img src="../content/web/Employees/#:data.EmployeeID#.jpg" alt="#: data.EmployeeID #" />
                </td>
                <td class="details">
                   <span class="name">#: FirstName# #: LastName# </span>
                   <span class="title">Title: #: Title #</span>
                </td>
                <td class="country">
                    #: Country #
                </td>
                <td class="employeeID">
                   #: EmployeeID #
                </td>
           </tr>
        </script>
        <script>
           $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                      type: "odata",
                      transport: {
                          read: {
                              url: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Employees",
                          }
                      }
                    },
                    rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#rowTemplate").html()),
                    altRowTemplate: kendo.template($("#altRowTemplate").html()),
                    height: 550,
                  reorderable : true,
                  sortable :true
                });
           });
        </script>
        <style>
            .photo {
                width: 140px;
            }
            .details {
                width: 400px;
            }
            .name {
                display: block;
                font-size: 1.6em;
            }
            .title {
                display: block;
                padding-top: 1.6em;
            }
            .employeeID,
            .country {
                font-family: "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 50px;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #898989;
            }
            td.photo, .employeeID {
                text-align: center;
            }
            .k-grid-header .k-header {
                padding: 10px 20px;
            }
            .k-grid td {
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 100%);
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.05)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.15)));
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 100%);
                background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 100%);
                background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 100%);
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 100%);
                padding: 20px;
            }
            .k-grid .k-alt td {
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%);
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.2)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.1)));
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%);
                background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%);
                background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%);
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%);
            }
        </style>
    </div>
```

[here](http://dojo.telerik.com/uxuRa)  is the live example of issue

Comment: Please include example code in the questions. (External links are nice, but are dependent on external services.)

Comment: Does any one have solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like latest kendo has fixed this issue .